# Au printemps la... « perdriole » etc. ?

Tags: paroles-de-chanson, jeux-de-mots

Dans une émission pour enfants on trouve une espèce de ritournelle :

> Au printemps, la [perdri](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/perdrix)[ole](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-ole),
>  Au printemps, la perdriole,
>  Fit
> son nid dans un buisson, la **\pivɔl\**,
>  Fit son nid dans un
> buisson, **\pivɔlɔ̃\** !
>
> [ Passe-Partout - Épisode 85 - Au Printemps, La Perdriole (1979), [à
> 1:40](https://youtu.be/ot2TXXp5XME?t=98) ]

Comment retranscrit-on les éléments en gras ; *perdriole* signifie-t-il autre chose qu'une « petite perdrix » ; peut-on brièvement expliquer le tout est plaisant ou amusant et ce qu'on doit en comprendre s'il y a lieu : y a-t-il dans le deuxième cas un emploi de la deuxième personne du pluriel pour évoquer la troisième du singulier ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*La pie vole*, un début de réponse :

[La pie voleuse](https://www.caminteresse.fr/animaux/pourquoi-dit-on-que-la-pie-est-voleuse-1193256/) est un oiseau donc il y a un jeu de mots avec les deux sens de voler, la pie qui vole dans l'air est une pie qui peut chaparder.  C'est une bavarde en plus.

*Pie, volons* ou *puis volons* ?

Si l'on s'adresse à la pie ou si les paroles sont « puis, volons » c'est l'impératif, une suggestion (l'hortatif). Je ne dirais pas qu'il s'agit de la troisième personne du singulier mais de la 2è pl. pour inviter la pie ou les autres à voler (ou à s'envoler).

Dans la comptine classique [Une Perdriole](https://youtu.be/BIQivuFAObw), l'enfant donne plusieurs animaux à mamie dont le premier est « la perdriole qui vient qui va qui vole. »

Answer (score 2):

Vieux français : hôler v. Crier comme la hulotte …la perdrix hôle. Elle cri comme la chouette hulotte. Surement en faisant référence à son battement d’ailes caractéristique.

Comment: Bienvenue ! Intéressant : https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/holer.

Comment: Est-ce la source de la définition ?